# Convert Numpy Array to Monotone Graph (networkx)

Tags: python, numpy, networkx

I have a simple array of 1s and 0s, and I want to convert this array to a graph using NetworkX with the following conditions:

- monotone
- Directional
- Weighted graph (go/no go areas)
- Starts in the lower left hand corner and works right

There is a built in function called `from_numpy_matrix`

See [this](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.7/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html)

The goal is to take this graph and show that I can get from the lower left hand corner of the matrix (think raster dataset) to the upper right hand corner without moving backwards or down.

Example array:

```
array = [[0,0,1,0,0],
         [1,0,0,1,0],
         [1,0,1,1,0],
         [0,0,1,1,0]]
myarray = np.array(array)
```

`0 means go area, 1 means blocked.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That was fun.

`from_numpy_matrix` doesn't help as there is no simple transformation from your maze to an adjacency matrix. Instead it is much easier to iterate over allowed positions (i.e. "not wall") and check if there is an allowed position in the allowed directions (up, right, diagonal up-right).

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def maze_to_graph(is_wall, allowed_steps):
    """
    Arguments:
    ----------
    is_wall       -- 2D boolean array marking the position of walls in the maze
    allowed_steps -- list of allowed steps; e.g. [(0, 1), (1, 1)] signifies that
                     from coming from tile (i, j) only tiles (i, j+1) and (i+1, j+1)
                     are reachable (iff there is no wall)

    Returns:
    --------
    g             -- networkx.DiGraph() instance
    pos2idx       -- dict mapping (i, j) position to node idx (for testing if path exists)
    idx2pos       -- dict mapping node idx to (i, j) position (for plotting)
    """

    # map array indices to node indices and vice versa
    node_idx = range(np.sum(~is_wall))
    node_pos = zip(*np.where(~is_wall))
    pos2idx = dict(zip(node_pos, node_idx))

    # create graph
    g = nx.DiGraph()
    for (i, j) in node_pos:
        for (delta_i, delta_j) in allowed_steps: # try to step in all allowed directions
            if (i+delta_i, j+delta_j) in pos2idx: # i.e. target node also exists
                g.add_edge(pos2idx[(i,j)], pos2idx[(i+delta_i, j+delta_j)])

    idx2pos = dict(zip(node_idx, node_pos))

    return g, idx2pos, pos2idx

def test():
    arr = np.array([[0,0,1,0,0],
                    [1,0,0,1,0],
                    [1,0,1,1,0],
                    [0,0,1,1,0]]).astype(np.bool)

    steps = [(0, 1),  # right
             (-1, 0), # up
             (-1, 1)] # diagonal up-right

    g, idx2pos, pos2idx = maze_to_graph(arr, steps)

    nx.draw(g, pos=idx2pos, node_size=1200, node_color='w', labels=idx2pos)

    start = (3, 0)
    stop = (0, 4)
    print "Has path: ", nx.has_path(g, pos2idx[start], pos2idx[stop])

    return
```

[image]

Comment: so for the first input, I would take my 1/0 array and if the value is 0, set it to False and where it is 1 set it to True?  is  allowed_steps just a set of coordinate points that can be used?  So {(0,0), (0,1), (1,1)...}?

Comment: 1) Yes, just convert your array of ones and zeros to booleans (as I do in the test() function, where I use the example you provided). 2) Allowed steps are not the allowed coordinate points. They are the index increments corresponding to the steps that you would in principle be allowed to take ignoring any walls. So (1, 0) is an increment of your first index by 1 and no increment in the second (effectively, you move 1 tile down in the maze).